# Python script to open and edit cells in a libre office Calc document?

Tags: python, cells, libreoffice-calc

An interesting problem I stumbled across- would it be possible for a python script to open up a calc document and change the values of cells? Absolutely no idea how to approach that, suggestions welcome :)

Comment: you can try openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)

Answer (score 0):

I have flagged this as a duplicate.

However, the odfpy library should help you with this:
https://github.com/eea/odfpy as an example.

Comment: This could 've been a comment.